# How to see the current status and maintenance rules of statistics in PostgreSQL, by analogy with the DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-administration

How to see the current status and maintenance rules of statistics in PostgreSQL, by analogy with the DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS command from MSSQL?
And also interested in how best to measure index fragmentation and page density in PostgreSQL?
Those, in summary, I need to understand how often and correctly the database is maintained in terms of statistics and indexes.

Comment: what is "page density"? And what exactly does this "dbcc" thing gives you?

Comment: I mean, how to get value of index fragmetation. DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS command displays current query optimization statistics for a table or indexed view. The query optimizer uses statistics to estimate the cardinality or number of rows in the query result, which enables the Query Optimizer to create a high quality query plan.

Comment: You can see the statistics used for a query using [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html). The statistics for tables are stored in [pg_statistic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-statistic.html)  [extended statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html) are stored in [pg_statistic_ext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-statistic-ext.html)

Comment: I don't know what "index fragmentation" is supposed to be.